# pyspark lag function (based on row)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to achieve if it is increased up to 100 so I can say that it is overpriced. Assume that time to time, the price varies within the day.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('product').orderBy('date')

display(market_price.withColumn('new_price', f.lag('price', 1, 0).over(w))
        .select('market_date', 'new_price')
       )
```

OUTPUT:

```
+---+-----------------------------------------+
|   |          date               | new_price |
+---+-----------------------------------------+
|   |2011-01-01T04:07:28.000+0000 |    0      |
|   |2011-01-01T04:07:50.000+0000 |   110     |
|   |2011-01-01T04:08:30.000+0000 |   150     |
|   |2011-01-01T04:09:45.000+0000 |   280     |
+---+-----------------------------------------+
```

MY DESIRE OUTPUT:

```
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|   |          date               | new_price  |    status      |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|   |2011-01-01T04:07:28.000+0000 |    0       | not overpriced |
|   |2011-01-01T04:07:50.000+0000 |   110      | not overpriced |
|   |2011-01-01T04:08:30.000+0000 |   150      | not overpriced |
|   |2011-01-01T04:09:45.000+0000 |   280      | overpriced     |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

see here that the last column is overpriced because from 150 -> 280.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think you want as it takes you input table and produces the output table.

```
market_price
  .withColumn( "old_price", lag("id", 1, 0).over(winowSpec) ) //get the previous price
  .select( 
    col("date"), 
    col("price") , 
    when( //if logic uses 'when'
      (col("price")-col("old_price")>100), //is the current price more than 100 over the old price
      "overpriced" ) // if true
    .otherwise("not overpriced") //otherwise if not > 100
    .alias("status") ) // rename the column
    .show()
```